# definition of order of a numerical integrator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I've seen two definitions of the "order" of an integrator for ordinary differential equations. The first (more common) one is that the method has order $k$ if the error introduced after one timestep $h$ is $O(h^{k+1})$. The second is that the method has order $k$ if it integrates a polynomial of degree $\le k$ exactly. For most common integrators (e.g., Runge-Kutta) the two definitions are equivalent.

Is there a general theorem on what conditions must be satisfied for the two definitions to be equivalent?

Comment: What do you assume about how the integrator works; are you assuming for example that it is a perhaps-multistep integrator for IVPs, so it takes some finite number of previous states and the timestep and returns the next state? (Note that this is not how e.g. collocation methods for BVP work.)

Comment: I guess for simplicity I'd like to assume that this is a one-step method for an initial-value problem, i.e. if the value of the vector variable is $z$ at time $t$, the integrator is some function $f(z,t,h)$ of $z$, $t$, and the timestep $h$ that predicts the value of $z(t+h)$.